the fluid duplicates the flow on its own, why?
Resolution Division is at 64 it does not show but when to number is increased to 100 or even 200 the fluid shows up in the middle of the domain see pictures below. any suggestions how to fix the duplicated flow





Did you bake the simulation ? What is the bake mode (modular VS all VS replay) ? That would be a great addition to your question. You can also share your blend file here : https://blend-exchange.com/

@Lutzi Yes i stimulated. my bake mode it set to to All

This feels like a cache issue but I have no clue. Did you apply scale ? For the domain and the fluid.

@Lutzi ,do you think i should re-save cache every time I re-bake ?

@Lutzi re-saving the cache to a new folder worked thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!

I've heard that before, that setting to a custom folder solves cache issue. No idea why. Glad it worked !
